# my dataset consists of (12-inputs,13 output)13 attributes , and i want to calculate metrics for each row of dataset but showing the error

Tags: keras, tf.keras

from numpy import loadtxt
   from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers import Dense
   from matplotlib import pyplot

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# load the dataset
dataset = loadtxt('train.csv', delimiter=',')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler.fit(dataset)
normalized = scaler.transform(dataset)

for row in normalized:

# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = row[0:13]
    y = row[13] 
# define the keras model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape'])

history =model.fit(X, y, epochs=20,batch_size=1 , verbose=2)

pyplot.plot(history.history['mse'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mae'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mape'])
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: i have a dataset of 13 attributes with 12 inputs and 1 output...of 50 rows.....and i want to calculate the metrics for each row of dataset..but showing error( Error when checking input: expected dense_138_input to have shape (13,) but got array with shape (1,) ) at history =model.fit(X, y, epochs=20,batch_size=1 , verbose=2)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, the shape of your input ***X*** in `model.fit` is not in the correct shape. The model expects the input to be an array of shape ***(13,)*** but the input to the model is ***(1,)*** shaped array. Print X and y values and verify if they are getting stored as list of lists as in `X = [[1,2,3,4,...13]] and Y = [[0]]` like this. In that case give `X[0] and y[0]` in `model.fit` method.

Comment: sir...its not getting..pls give me your mail_id..........i will mail you sir